# react material ui Typescript: adding custom property to theme

Tags: reactjs, typescript, debugging, material-ui

I was trying to override default interface of material ui Theme to add a custom background property to palette.

The problem solved thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/a/66087432/8352921 solution by [deewens](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12308243/deewens).

```
declare module '@material-ui/core/styles/createPalette'
```

But there were many posts to use `createMuiTheme`. For this kind of issues, how can we find whats the exact module we should fix. in this case `@material-ui/core/styles/createPalette` without googling and spending much time searching for the issue. Is there specific steps I can use to debug this efficiently.

Answer (score 0):

I found the main reason for this as, the theme options interface is located in `createPalette`.

Comment: Can't verify this. What version of `mui` are you on?

Comment: this is mui4, you can check inside the createPalette module